# How do Tiles take less memory than bigger Images

Tags: c#, image, game-engine, tile

Okay so lets picture this:

1) You have a 64x64 pixels png file painted all red.

You load the thing, you put it in a Texture-type variable, 
write a position variable and you draw it.

2) You have a 32x32 pixels png file painted all red.

You load the thing.

You write a class for a Tile, which will contain the Texture variable and position variable, and a function to draw it.

Lastly you define a Tile[2,2] array, pass loaded texture (tile) to EACH Tile instance and set positions of those 4 32x32's to look like that previous example 64x64 image.

Now my question is how does 2)nd way use less memory if every of those 4 Tile instances contain the texture. Is texture here just a reference ?

Comment: I think you're going to need to share some code. And "ong" -> "png".

Comment: All objects are references... if you reuse a same object multiple times, then yes, unless you save that bigger combined image in memory as new image object, it's still only in memory once. It just gets painted on the screen multiple times, from the same memory.